# How can I pull a group-based vector to pass to a function within dplyr's summarize or mutate?

Tags: r, tidyverse, dplyr, summarize

I am trying to create a summary table of accuracy, sensitivity, and specificity using the `AUC` function within the `psych` package. I would like to define the input vector (t, a 4 x 1 vector) for each level of the grouped variable.

What I have tried seems to ignore the grouping.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

Data <- data.frame(Class = c("A","B","C","D"),
                   TP = c(198,185,221,192),
                   FP = c(1,1,6,1),
                   FN = c(42,55,19,48),
                   TN = c(569,570,564,569))

Data %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>%
  mutate(Accuracy = AUC(t = unlist(.[1,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Accuracy,
         Sensitivity = AUC(t = unlist(.[1,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Sensitivity,
         Specificity = AUC(t = unlist(.[1,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Specificity)
```

This gives me close to the correct output, except the values for Accuracy, Sensitivity, and Specificity are only being calculated with the first row, then repeated:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   Class [4]
  Class    TP    FP    FN    TN Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A       198     1    42   569    0.947       0.995       0.931
2 B       185     0    55   570    0.947       0.995       0.931
3 C       221     6    19   564    0.947       0.995       0.931
4 D       192     1    48   569    0.947       0.995       0.931
```

I have also tried with `summarize`:

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>%
  summarize(Accuracy = AUC(t = unlist(.[1,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Accuracy,
         Sensitivity = AUC(t = unlist(.[1,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Sensitivity,
         Specificity = AUC(t = unlist(.[1,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Specificity)
```

But the output is the same as above.

The desired output is a unique calculation for each level of "Class"

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
  Class    TP    FP    FN    TN Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1 A       198     1    42   569     0.95        0.99        0.93
2 B       185     0    55   570     0.93        0.99        0.91
3 C       221     6    19   564     0.97        0.97        0.97
4 D       192     1    48   569     0.94        0.99        0.92
```

How do I get the function call within summarize or mutate to maintain the groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>%
  mutate(Accuracy = AUC(t = unlist(.[Class,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Accuracy,
         Sensitivity = AUC(t = unlist(.[Class,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Sensitivity,
         Specificity = AUC(t = unlist(.[Class,2:5], use.names=FALSE))$Specificity)
```

but maybe this is more clear

```
Data %>% 
  group_by(Class) %>%
  mutate(Accuracy = AUC(t = c(TP, FP, FN, TN))$Accuracy,
         Sensitivity = AUC(t = c(TP, FP, FN, TN))$Sensitivity,
         Specificity = AUC(t = c(TP, FP, FN, TN))$Specificity)
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid calling `AUC` several times for each class, I'd write a wrapper, like this:

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(psych)

# Create data frame
Data <- data.frame(Class = c("A","B","C","D"),
                   TP = c(198,185,221,192),
                   FP = c(1,1,6,1),
                   FN = c(42,55,19,48),
                   TN = c(569,570,564,569))

# Wrapper function
AUC_wrapper <- function(Class, TP, FP, FN, TN){
  res <- AUC(t = c(TP, FP, FN, TN))
  data.frame(Class = Class, 
             TP = TP,
             FP = FP,
             FN = FN,
             TN = TN,
             Accuracy = res$Accuracy, 
             Sensitivity = res$Sensitivity, 
             Specificity = res$Specificity)
}

# Run using purrr
pmap_dfr(Data, AUC_wrapper)

#   Class  TP FP FN  TN  Accuracy Sensitivity Specificity
# 1     A 198  1 42 569 0.9469136   0.9949749   0.9312602
# 2     B 185  1 55 570 0.9309494   0.9946237   0.9120000
# 3     C 221  6 19 564 0.9691358   0.9735683   0.9674099
# 4     D 192  1 48 569 0.9395062   0.9948187   0.9222042
```

Comment: This is dropping the `Class` names and outputting factor levels for me